# Set UIButton's Text To Date

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIButton that when clicked brings up a UIDatePicker that will set it's date.

Everything is set up with the animation in and out, etc.

What I need help with:

Setting the button's text label to the day's date by default.  And then also setting it to the newly selected date after the UIDatePicker is dismissed.

```
 - (IBAction)dateButtonPressed
{
    [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:dateView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }];
}

- (IBAction)dismssPicker
{
    [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){ [dateView removeFromSuperview]; }];
}
```

Comment: if you searched stackoverflow for 1 minute you would have found your answer by now.

Comment: I spent about 20 min searching and did not find any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change you method to this. (I'm assuming you have connected this to UIDatePicker)

```
 -(IBAction)dismssPicker:(UIDatePicker*)datePicker
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    NSDate *date = datePicker.date;
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"]; 
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; 
//set it now


    [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){ [dateView removeFromSuperview]; }];
}
```

For your next problem, make as `NSDate *prvDate;` in your .h file

```
-(IBAction)changeDate:(id)sender{
    prvDate = yourCurrentDate;  //save your previous date 
    yourCurrentDate = datePicker.date;
//set the button's label here
}

 -(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{
    yourCurrentDate = prvDate;
//set the button's label here
}
```

Comment: I actually got it working after just connecting in IB and it seems to work fine now.  Should I still change my method to the on you just posted here?

Comment: no if its working fine then don't... I think you have connect this method to a UIButton. You can connect it to date picker also. Try it for testing only.

Comment: One simple thing if you know the answer Inder.  I have two buttons: "Change Date" and Cancel".  I want the change date code to run if the change date button is pressed only so I will make an IF statement.  How do I make the condition that says "If the change date button pressed, do yadadadadaaada...."

Answer (score 1):

you probably want something like:

```
[button setTitle:[[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d"
                                    timezone:nil
                                      locale:nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
```

to change the text of the button.

like

```
[button setTitle:[date description] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Comment: It's is now upto you.. change your code. Reflog and I have given you the suggestions.

Comment: I think I should set the label to the default day's date in viewDidLoad, and then set it to the new date in the dismissPicker if the date was changed, correct?

Comment: also, i tried using your code but it didn't work.  I think I need a NSDateFormatter?

Comment: Yes, and you dont need to check whether date has changed or not just set it simply.

Comment: Can you help set up a NSDateFormatter?  I tired the following but no luck:    `NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d y"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return dateString`

Comment: Yeah surely it need NSDateFormatter to format your date. I just simply set it for my ease. Just send me the type of date you want.. like 14-09-2011

Comment: `NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d y"]; 
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];`
    NSLog(@"Date is = %@",dateString);`  and the output was like  `Date is = Apr 14 2011`

Comment: `NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"]; 
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Date is = %@",dateString);` for your date format

Comment: Thanks, i got the button set to today's date by default. Now one more thing, when user changes date and clicks the submit button, how can I get that new date so I can set that to the button's title?

Comment: `- (IBAction)dismssPicker
{
//get the date here and set as you set in view didLoad

 

//your code
}`

Comment: yah i know how to set it, but my question is, how do I retrieve the date from the UIDatePicker?

Comment: HAe to studied UIDatePicker class references if not then you should. Let c who will get the answer first

Comment: Could you tell me how you have connected this IBAction to UIDatePicker  like valueChanged of something else

Comment: I tried this but no luck, NSLog shows null: `NSDate *myDate = picker.date;
    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d y"]; 
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]; 
    NSLog(@"New Date is = %@",dateString);`